# ASP.NET Music in Background on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, background, postback

I'm currently working on a Website for a school project.
We have to create a little game.

For this Game I would like to play some music in the background. So my question is, is it possible to play music in Background, without interrupting it on a PostBack? Like if the user presses a Button.

And how would I implement something like this? :)

.

Maybe someone has a nice idea! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full postback will interrupt the background music, no matter what*.

You will have to either use AJAX for calling a partial postback (that would reload just the specific user control instead of the entire page), or apply JavaScript click events and declare corresponding WebMethods instead of ASP click events.

*OK, actually you can create a popup or an iframe for your music player, but both of these options are terrible.